# UIViewController Reuse Cell and change Label inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sigabrt

So my Problem is that i get a SIGABRT Error with the following definition:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell ZellenBeschreibung]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf6b7526f0'
```

The part that crashes in "Karte1CVC.m":

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Karte1Zelle *Zelle = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
Zelle.ZellenBeschreibung.Text = [Beschreibungen objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]; //----- Here the Crash happens
return Zelle;
```

When i delete this Part it works without a SIGABRT Error. But my then i see nothing on the screen.
My UICollectionViewCell is Classed "Karte1Zelle".

Karte1Zelle.h

```
@interface Karte1Zelle : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ZellenBeschreibung;
```

I did connect my Storyboards.

UICollectionViewController to Karte1CVC

My Cell to Karte1Zelle

So can anyone help me with this Problem?

Comment: Did you set the class of cell in Storyboard to `Karte1Zelle`?

Comment: Have you set your `reuseIdentifier` correctly? It must be exactly the same in your Storyboard and your code.

Comment: Try lower case text Zelle.ZellenBeschreibung.text

Comment: Also @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ZellenBeschreibung; should be weak instead of strong.

Comment: Did now everything you told me still same as b4

Comment: you have to register your class to the collectionview!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With collection view there are something that you have to do like adding a UICollectionViewFlowLayout or register the cell that you are using.
You can do it with code:

```
 [collectionView registerClass:[Karte1Zelle class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Karte1Zelle"];
```